# R data.table aggregate by date and another variable

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a big `data.table` (about 1.8M observations on 57 variables). In the original data, there's one variable with date and time as character, which I successfully converted to `POSIXct`. A scaled-down version of my data could be downloaded from [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh04eurd1e77e29/exampleDF.RData?dl=0)

In order to obtain daily totals, I can aggregate the `$value` by:

```
exampleDF[,list(value.sum=sum(value)),by=as.Date(dateTime)]
```

and even by:

```
exampleDF[,list(value.sum=sum(value)),by=month(as.Date(dateTime))]
```

What I haven't been able to do is to aggregate by `dateTime` and **another** variable:

```
exampleDF[,list(value.sum=sum(value)),by=c("category","place")]    #--This WORKS, but
exampleDF[,list(value.sum=sum(value)),by=c("category",as.Date("dateTime"))] #-- This doesn't work
```

I've tried many combinations using quotation marks, `list`, but haven't found the correct one, I'll appreciate your kind help on how to make it work.

Comment: Try `exampleDF[,list(value.sum=sum(value)),by=list(category,as.Date(dateTime))]` maybe

Comment: @DavidArenburg I tried a very close one, but kept the `"`, that definitely worked, would you provide an answer, so I can mark it as such? Thanks!

Comment: It's fine, you can answer it yourself.

Comment: Or just delete. This is documented in `help("data.table")`.

Comment: @Roland can you cite where it's mentioned that you can pass functions of variables in `by`? That's news to me, actually.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Those are not functions, but expressions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm thinking in math again...